# Advanced android layout: making a ListView divider from a layer-list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Refer to the image below to understand what I'm trying to do. It should be obvious from the image provided. It seems like this should be pretty simple.

The question is, why is the tiled middle section offset by an inconsistent amount for each list entry?

**product_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:divider="@drawable/product_list_divider"
              android:background="@drawable/main_background_bitmap"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="No results."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**product_list_divider.xml**

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_middle"
            android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_left"
            android:gravity="left"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_right"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Image to help explain the situation...]

Comment: That is really odd... it looks as if it is flipping the middle upside down for half of them... Are you using a custom adapter?

Comment: No, it was a standard SimpleCursorAdapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the repeat tile mode and did it like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/bg"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_shine"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_middle_stretch"
            android:gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_side_left"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_side_right"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_left"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_right"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```