# Android ListView divider doesn't move when it's tiled bitmap

Tags: android, android-listview, android-drawable

I'm trying to use a repeating image as a divider for a ListView.

First I define an bitmap drawable for the background like this:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern_delimiter">
</bitmap>
```

I get the image stretched, as expected.

[image]

So let's specify a **tileMode**:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern_delimiter"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >
</bitmap>
```

Now it looks like this, and when I scroll the ListView, the images stay in place

[image]

The problem is that the images do not move as I scroll the ListView, it appears as if Android pre-rendered the whole repeating image and the actual dividers are only a transparent area through which the pre-renderer dividers are visible.

That is not what I wanted, as I expected that I'll see the dividers move with the list items.

Is there a way to repeat the image **and** have it move along with the list?

Comment: Seems like tiled divider doesnt work that way, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061887/advanced-android-layout-making-a-listview-divider-from-a-layer-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it has something with Android recycling list view items.
My quick solution would be moving the divider to the row's xml.

Comment: That's how I did it in the end, but I don't like the fact that now I have to hide the divider for the first (or last) item